# why error when Converting Angular Web Application into Ionic App?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

```
> ng run angular-ionic:ionic-cordova-build --platform=android
An unhandled exception occurred: Project target does not exist.
See "/private/var/folders/yg/4t31gc151s922j50sg38lj8w0000gn/T/ng-7qY1pc/angular-errors.log" for further details.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.
        
        ng run angular-ionic:ionic-cordova-build --platform=android exited with
        exit code 127.
        
        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more
        information.
```

I have this error when I try this tutorial :
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/converting-angular-web-application-into-ionic-app-5af678325626

This is my repository:
https://github.com/KarineVinette/example-angular-ionic

Comment: could you show us your angular.json file ?

Comment: You can look at my repository

Comment: Check this link "https://dev.to/tbsraviashara/build-a-native-app-from-angular-projects-with-capacitor-40pk"

Comment: When I try ```npx cap run android```, I have ```device:offline```